# Аналог криптопровайдера КриптоПро CSP

Tags: c#, криптография, windows-server, цифровая-подпись, windows-server-2012

Имеется машина с **Windows Server 2012**. Пробовали подписать файлы через **КриптоПро CSP**, но увы, данный криптопровайдер является платным. Работаю с сертификатом с закрытым ключом, код пишем на C#. Пришли к выводу, что без установки криптопровайдера не обойтись. Имеется ли бесплатный сертифицированный криптопровайдер для подписи файлов? Установку производить буду на сервер, поэтому сразу вопрос, подойдет ли ПО?

Comment: Что именно вы подразумеваете под "сертифицированным" провайдером? Провайдер с государственной сертификацией на соответствие с ГОСТ?

Comment: @PashaPash, да-да, по ГОСТ

Comment: В моем прошлом месте работы писали софт для гос. сектора, в т.ч. работали с криптопровайдерами и пользовались КриптоПро. Думаю если бы был бесплатный сертифицированный аналог, им бы воспользовались.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, вот тоже подходим к такому выводу, что бесплатного сертифицированного аналога **КриптоПро** не найдем... Чтож, подождем еще мнений. Спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: @DenisBubnov: Извините, но из Вашего вопроса не понятно, *что* Вы пытаетесь реализовать. Речь идет о "подписи файлов" "сертификатом с закрытым ключом" без каких либо деталей. Каких файлов, например? Некоторые форматы файлов предусматривает встроенную подпись, как exe/dll. Для подписи других можно создать .cat (каталог) файл и хэшами файлов и подписать этот каталог. Последнее можно сделать используя стандартные средства Windows и стандартный криптопровайдер типа "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider".

Comment: @Oleg, есть такая библиотека iTextCharp, которая позволяет подписывать файлы (pdf), для работы с ней нужен сертификат, и криптопровайдер, который обеспечивает шифрование с помощью определенного алгоритма. Из алгоритмов там есть RSA, SHA, и прочие. Без криптопровайдера никак не достучаться до токена и не вытащить нужный сертификат с закрытым ключом. А библиотека **Крипто .Net** позволяет использовать ГОСТ алгоритмы шифрования.

Comment: @DenisBubnov: Я не знаком ГОСТми и не знаю какие алгоритмы шифрования (? или все же подписи) включены в ГОСТ. Но на первый взгляд iTextCharp использует стандартный X509Certificate и Вам должно быть достаточно "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider" который поддерживает RSA и SHA как для подписи так и шифрования.

Comment: @Oleg  ГОСТ Р 34.10–2012. - это самостоятельный алгоритм, а не просто сборка из существующих. Он приниципиален для использования в некоторых (гос)конторах. ФСБ занимается сертификацией реализаций. Топикастер ищет реализацию этого алгоритма, в виде криптопровайдера, бесплатную, и сертифицированную. На мой взгляд, никто не будет заморачиватся с реализацией кастомного алгоритма, да еще и с сертификацией ее через ФСБ, чтобы потом раздавать его бесплатно. Но вдруг...

Comment: @PashaPash: Спасибо за разъяснение! Просто ГОСТ - это какой либо Государственный стандарт не указанный в вопросе. ГОСТ Р 34.10–2012., ГОСТ 34.10-94 или др. - это уже вполне конкретный стандарт. Он для меня ужасно напоминает RSA. Но в таком случае исходный вопрос - это практически исключительно правовой вопрос, а не программисткий. Я полагаю, что в программе не потребуется менять ни одной строки, а только конфигурационный файл, где указан, например, используемый криптографический провайдер. Я правильно теперь понимаю?

Comment: @Oleg, криптопровайдер я указываю в коде. Вот пример: `Gost3410CryptoServiceProvider cert_key = certificate.PrivateKey as Gost3410CryptoServiceProvider;`  **certificate** имеет тип **X509Certificate2**

Comment: @Oleg да, правильно, он и должен напоминать RSA, просто он отечественный (тм) и сертифицированный. и готовые реализации - жутко дороги.

Comment: @DenisBubnov: Я не знаком с `Gost3410CryptoServiceProvider`, но сама идея CryptoAPI в Windows и далее в .Net классах состояла в том, чтобы **инстанциировать провайдеры по имени и по набору предоставляемых алгоритмов**. Например, можно использовать `RSACryptoServiceProvider` с `CspParameters` в котором задан Gost3410 провайдер по имени. После этого все зопросы перенаправляются провайдеру. Например, для поддержки smart card нажно лишь установить провайдер для hardware и та же Ваша программа может читать и подписывать сартификатами со smart card.

Comment: Vipnet csp бесплатен при регистрации продукта. только не знаю работает ли он на серверах.